# How to mock the route object in Vue 3 composition?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-test-utils, vitest

I'd like to mock the route object to prevent test failures like `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined` when accessing `route.x`.

I tried:

```
const route = { fullPath: '/', path: '/' };

const options = {
  mocks: {
    route,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the route object is no longer a global object you have to do the following:

```
const route = { fullPath: '/', path: '/' };

vi.mock('vue-router', () => ({
  useRoute: () => route,
}));
```